# Mocking Autowire in a class

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I have an XYZ class which is autowired in ABC and in class MyClass I have a method name doSomething() inside that method I do ABC abc = new ABC(); Then I call abc.someMethod();

Please see code sample below :

Class ABC

```
public class ABC {

  @Autowire
  private XYZ xyz;

  public void someMethod()
  {
   //Some stuff
   xyz.someFunc();

  }
}
```

Class MyCLass

```
public class MyCLass {

  public void doSomething() {
    ABC abc = new ABC();
    abc.someMethod();
  }
}
```

Need unit test doSomething() but I NPE as XYZ is null in ABC. How can I mock @Autowire in this case.

Comment: Just as an FYI, as soon as you use `new ABC()` to construct a bean, any Spring annotations will not work (i.e. autowiring will not work). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null

Answer (score 0):

If you use constructor injection instead of field injection, you can create the mock and give it to the constructor of ABC:

```
public class ABC {

    private final XYZ xyz;

    public ABC(XYZ xyz) {
        this.xyz = xyz;
    }

    public void someMethod()
    {
        //Some stuff
        xyz.someFunc();

    }
}
```

Then in your test, when you create the instance under test, you just create it and hand over the mock:

```
XYZ mock = mock(XYZ.class);

ABC underTest = new ABC(mock);
```

Comment: I dont have the access to modify the ABC code its owned by another entity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following testing capabilities in your test:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
```

Provide a configuration and use it, for example:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyTest.MyTestConfiguration.class)
public class MyTest {

    // xyz injected into ABC and MyTest for convenience.
    @Autowired
    private XYZ xyz;

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        // Some Stubbing...
        when(xyz.trySomething()).thenReturn(true);

        // Some verification.
        new ABC().doSomething();
        verify(xyz, times(1))
                .trySomething();
    }

    // Note it is used in @ContextConfiguration
    @Configuration
    static class MyTestConfiguration {
        @Bean
        XYZ xyz() {
            return mock(XYZ.class);
        }
    }
}
```

The documentation is a bit extensive, search for the mentioned annotations here https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing

Comment: This did not work :(

Comment: I just edited the answer, added `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`. I've used this plenty of times, though I may have missed some details.